# How to restore the shortcut for the "fancy window switch?

Tags: 10.04, shortcut-keys

Pressing the <kbd>Super</kbd> key and <kbd>tab</kbd> `<Mod4+Tab>` used to work similar to pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (which switches windows just like M$), but it showed a much better preview. Somehow I lost the shortcut and can't find it anymore. I've gone through the chaos in **System -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts** several times and the only thing I can see there is **Move between windows, using a popup window**, whatever that means.

I prefer the "fancier" switcher, how can I restore it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you mean this:

[image]

If this is what you had, you can use CompizConfig Settings Manager to edit that.

To get it, enter this into terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

After it installs, go to **Window Management > Shift Switcher** and enable it. When you do this, you should get a popup about key bindings. Select **Resolve Conflicts** and select **Disable Exit Expo** (Or something like that).

If you don't have CCSM, I'm not entirely too sure how you got that. I only know of how to use it through CCSM, but others may be able to help.

Comment: You're right, it was it. Your install command didn't work for me, but Software Center did. The Shift Switcher works now, thx a lot.

Comment: Glad to hear that it works :) I love the fancy window switch...so much more dynamic than the alt-tab one. I edited my answer and changed ccsm to the correct package name...stupid me. Thanks for letting me know that "ccsm" didn't work!